# calling pattern search in vectorized function

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a vectorized function which is an objective function for an optimizer (genetic algorithm).

Inside this function, there is a fast optimization which is part of the computation of this function as follow:

```
function error = ObjectiveFunction(a, b, c)
    x = a.*b;
    y = c.*b;
    z = patternsearch(@fun, [x, y]);
    error = x+y.*z;
end

solution = ga(@ObjectiveFunction, 'vectorized', true);
```

`ObjectiveFunction` accepts vector of solution. This makes `ga` works faster. However, since inside `ObjectiveFunction` there is `patternsearch` process, this vectorization will be useless because `patternsearch` (as an optimizer) does not work in vectorized manner.

So I had to edit my function to:

```
function error = ObjectiveFunction(a, b, c)
    x = a.*b;
    y = c.*b;
    for i = 1:size(x,1)
        z(i) = patternsearch(@fun, [x(i), y(i)]);
    end
    error = x+y.*z;
end
```

Is there anyway to replace the loop with a vectorized call to `patternsearch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using `arrayfun` as follow

```
function error = ObjectiveFunction(a, b, c)
    x = a.*b;
    y = c.*b;
    z = arrayfun(@(x1,y1) patternsearch(@fun, [x1, y1]),x,y);       
    error = x+y.*z;
end
```

I hope this may help